# Shortcut key to impliment an interface in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Can anyone let me know what are all the shortcut keys used in visual studio while doing C# coding?like Shortcut key to impliment an interface in visual studio?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Tools + Customize, Keyboard.  Bind a key to the Edit.ImplementInterfaceStubsImplicitly command.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't one. Here is a good reference:

http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/

Comment: Zdravko, Thanks that was really helpful. But do you know the shortcut keys like const + double tab for constructor?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're thinking of Code Snippets?

Typing "interface" within a namespace, class or struct creates an interface declaration.

[Visual Studio Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx)

Comment: Got it!!  Thanks Lurker, for answering m question.